# Importing gmail/yahoo/hotmail/aol address book with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gmail, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to import address book of users from their gmail/hotmail/yahoo and aol address books. I am looking for a gem/plugin in rails which can help me do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best plugin to fetch Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Twitter and Facebook contact list in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311132/whats-the-best-plugin-to-fetch-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-twitter-and-facebook-conta)

Answer (score 1):

Ive been trying **Contacts**:

http://github.com/cardmagic/contacts

It allows to import contacts from gmail with 2 lines of code!!!
Works wonderfully for me.
Still have to check out if it supports insertion and syncing (??) maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I once used a gem called Blackbook: http://github.com/purzelrakete/blackbook

It supports a number of email services. But seems it hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: neutrino, blackbook is scrapping based and such types of contact fetching architecture breaks when the providers such as gmail change their user interface to the slightest bits.