# Issues in fetching address book to fetch Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Twitter and Facebook contact list in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, contacts, social-networking

Came across the [Contacts](https://github.com/mislav/contacts) plugin while searching.

But as per the usage, described in the readme file. It requires username and password to fetch contacts. But that's not a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mini FB plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmuaT.png) for Facebook login. It also allows me to fetch users contacts. So I can use this one for Facebook. [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) is another solution for fetching facebook friends

**FACEBOOK UPDATE**

Here i got the solution for facebook, but i it just show me invite friends for facebook

```
    <div id="facebook_invites" class="conclusion" style="width: 750px; text-align: center">
      <a id="wall_post" href="#" style="font-size: 2em;">Post on your Wall</a><br/>
      <a id="invite_friends" href="#" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Invite your Friends</a>
      </div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>


      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#wall_post').click(function() {
            FB.init({
              appId:'app_id', cookie:true,
              status:true, xfbml:true
            });

            FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
              link: 'http://localhost:3000/',
              picture: 'http://localhost:3000/',
              description: 'abc is cool.',
              name: 'abc.com'});
          });

          $('#invite_friends').click(function() {
            FB.init({
              appId:'app_id', cookie:true,
              status:true, xfbml:true
            });

            FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
              message: 'abc is cool.'});
          });
        </script>
```

---

---

**Google Update**

From [google developers guide](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_js.html), we have a section "Retrieving all contacts", But in between there is a line written ie:-

***Note: Retrieving another user's contacts is not supported by the current version of the Contacts API.***

```
   /*
    * Retrieve all contacts
    */

    // Create the contacts service object
    var contactsService =
       new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');

    // The feed URI that is used for retrieving contacts
    var feedUri = 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';
    var query = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactQuery(feedUri);

    // Set the maximum of the result set to be 50
    query.setMaxResults(50);

    // callback method to be invoked when getContactFeed() returns data
    var callback = function(result) {

     // An array of contact entries
     var entries = result.feed.entry;

     // Iterate through the array of contact entries
     for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
       var contactEntry = entries[i];

       var emailAddresses = contactEntry.getEmailAddresses();

       // Iterate through the array of emails belonging to a single contact entry
       for (var j = 0; j < emailAddresses.length; j++) {
         var emailAddress = emailAddresses[j].getAddress();
         PRINT('email = ' + emailAddress);
       }    
     }
    }

    // Error handler
    var handleError = function(error) {
     PRINT(error);
    }

    // Submit the request using the contacts service object
    contactsService.getContactFeed(query, callback, handleError);
```

**Another sever side solution for google contacts:
Solution for google:**

Get your client_id and client_secret from [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). This is rough script, which works perfectly fine. Modified it as per your needs.

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'net/https'
    require 'uri'
    require 'rexml/document'

    class ImportController < ApplicationController

      def authenticate
        @title = "Google Authetication"

        client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        google_root_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=profile&redirect_uri="+googleauth_url+"&response_type=code&client_id="+client_id.to_s+"&approval_prompt=force&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
        redirect_to google_root_url
      end

      def authorise
        begin
          @title = "Google Authetication"
          token = params[:code]
          client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          uri = URI('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

          request.set_form_data('code' => token, 'client_id' => client_id, 'client_secret' => client_secret, 'redirect_uri' => googleauth_url, 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code')
          request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          response = http.request(request)
          response.code
          access_keys = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)

          uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token="+access_keys['access_token'].to_s+"&max-results=50000&alt=json")

          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
          response = http.request(request)
          contacts = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
          contacts['feed']['entry'].each_with_index do |contact,index|

             name = contact['title']['$t']
             contact['gd$email'].to_a.each do |email|
              email_address = email['address']
              Invite.create(:full_name => name, :email => email_address, :invite_source => "Gmail", :user_id => current_user.id)  # for testing i m pushing it into database..
            end

          end  
        rescue Exception => ex
           ex.message
        end
        redirect_to root_path , :notice => "Invite or follow your Google contacts."


      end

    end
```

Screenshot for settings.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For [Gmail](https://rubygems.org/gems/gmail) or for your specific purpose: [Gmail Contacts](https://rubygems.org/gems/gmail_contacts).

For Yahoo contacts, as far as I know, [Contacts](http://github.com/mislav/contacts) seems to be the one that is used. If someone has a better alternative. Please do mention.

For Twitter, I would highly recommend the [Twitter](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) gem.

For Facebook, you already got your Facebook gem sorted. However, I personally use [FB Graph](https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph).

**Edit:**

Hmm, I tried having a look at the doc. No examples mentioned. Although it does mention:

> See sample/authsub.rb for an example
>   which uses GmailContacts

Which is nowhere to be found. Perhaps a quick email to the author might help?

It also seems that the the [Contacts gem](http://github.com/mislav/contacts) is quite well documented online. If you can find a way to work it out with your project requirements. Then you can use this as a universal solution for other email providers.

Alternatively, another way for contacts retrieval, I found [this](http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2008/04/18/import-gmail-contacts-using-ruby-on-rails/) which can be useful.

Comment: is there any example code for gmail contacts. I tried but didnt get anything.

Answer (score 1):

For Gmail rather than using any gem, you should use a sample code, it's not a worth the gem.

See my sample code here - https://gist.github.com/742461

Actually had a blog post here - http://rtdptech.com/2010/12/importing-gmail-contacts-list-to-rails-application/ but seems current it is facing redirection issues.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep track of which user's have invited who, via a join table. Here's the FB.ui JS w/ callback to get you started:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    title: t,
    message: m
},
function(response) {
  if (response) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/invitation_requests/create",
      data: { "requests[]" : response.request_ids },
      timeout: 12500,
      async : false, // This fixes an issue w/ IE
      complete: function() {
        $.cookie( "latest_request_ids", response.request_ids.length );
        window.location = "/users"
      }
    });
  }
});
```