# how to Import contacts via gmail in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues in fetching address book to fetch Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Twitter and Facebook contact list in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311132/issues-in-fetching-address-book-to-fetch-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-twitter-and-face)

I'm creating an app that people can add their friends to and I want to help them find them via gmail (like that facebook, twitter or foursquare do). I saw the [google api](http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/contacts/) for it and im pretty convinced that I need the "Portable Contacts API". My question is how do I do that in Rails?

Answer (score 11):

You could use OmniContacts: https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts

Diego

Comment: Do you have any example I can look at? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can find it here: https://github.com/sonianand11/omnicontacts_example

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at:

https://github.com/glennfu/contacts

You should be able to import Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail, AOL and Plaxo.

Comment: thank you , but with this gem i need to create my own connecting pages. how can i do it with the official connecting pages of the email sites?

Comment: so you need something to implement oauth?

Comment: yes, i want to connect them using this page http://bit.ly/ki4tj5