# How to get create an access token in ruby on rails for gmail contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, omniauth, google-contacts-api

I am using Omniauth to request the user gmail credentials, so I can request the user friends/contacts later.

Right now I am getting the friends list inside of the OmniauthCallbacks controller, using the access token that the authentication request generates for me. Something like this

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def google
    auth = env["omniauth.auth"]
    gmail_contacts
    ....
  end

  ..... 
  protected
  def gmail_contacts
    access_token = env["omniauth.auth"]['extra']['access_token']
    response = access_token.request(:get,  
       "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=10000")
    .....
  end
end
```

How can I use the credentials that I have stored in the database to create a new access token, so I can call google API from a different controller?

Comment: De Tester: Did you find a non detestable answer? :) Let us know.

Comment: @DavidJames check my answer. Just wrote today and working perfectly at my end..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best plugin to fetch Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Twitter and Facebook contact list in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311132/whats-the-best-plugin-to-fetch-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-twitter-and-facebook-conta)

Answer (score 3):

Get your client_id and client_secret from [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). This is rough script, which works perfectly fine. Modified it as per your needs.

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'net/https'
    require 'uri'
    require 'rexml/document'

    class ImportController < ApplicationController

      def authenticate
        @title = "Google Authetication"

        client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        google_root_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=profile&redirect_uri="+googleauth_url+"&response_type=code&client_id="+client_id.to_s+"&approval_prompt=force&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
        redirect_to google_root_url
      end

      def authorise
        begin
          @title = "Google Authetication"
          token = params[:code]
          client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          uri = URI('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

          request.set_form_data('code' => token, 'client_id' => client_id, 'client_secret' => client_secret, 'redirect_uri' => googleauth_url, 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code')
          request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          response = http.request(request)
          response.code
          access_keys = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)

          uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token="+access_keys['access_token'].to_s+"&max-results=50000&alt=json")

          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
          response = http.request(request)
          contacts = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
          contacts['feed']['entry'].each_with_index do |contact,index|

             name = contact['title']['$t']
             contact['gd$email'].to_a.each do |email|
              email_address = email['address']
              Invite.create(:full_name => name, :email => email_address, :invite_source => "Gmail", :user_id => current_user.id)  # for testing i m pushing it into database..
            end

          end  
        rescue Exception => ex
           ex.message
        end
        redirect_to root_path , :notice => "Invite or follow your Google contacts."


      end

    end
```

Screenshot for settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An idea - investigate whether the `params[:oauth_verifier]` that was sent from gmail will work in subsequent requests. But maybe it's only good for that one request.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts

It's great for getting contacts from gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc.  It's also very simple to use.